# Does feedback loop also apply to buffer access in OpenGL ES?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, gpu

I understand if reading and rendering to the same texture in gles, it would produce undefined results, the spec calls this "feedback loop".
However seems it doesn't mention whether this rule also applies to buffers or not.

Suppose vertex stage side effects is supported, if the vertex shader reads from an SSBO and the fragment shader of the same renderpass writes to it, would it be also undefined results?

Even if vertex stage side effects is not supported, I think the same situation also exists, like if a VBO is bound as an SSBO to be written by the fragment shader, is it also a "feedback loop"?

Comment: Whether it is undefined or not, I would say the short answer to this is "don't do it".  GPUs are designed to do bulk work, streaming data in and out with a potentially very long pipeline, and that is best done by having the source and destination as completely separate (or assumed separate! ) "memory" areas.

Answer (score 1):

The [rules with SSBOs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access) are a lot less strict than the rules of framebuffers (sans [texture-barrier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Barrier)). So long as you're not reading data from a location that the fragment shader actually attempt to, then it's fine. That is, your VSs can read from one region of the buffer while the FSs write to another.

It's also fine if there is a dependency between the specific vertex and fragment shaders. If the fragment shader is executing, then the vertex shaders which produced the specific vertices for the primitive that kicked off those fragment shaders *must* have completed execution. So as long as the reading VSs are only reading from locations that will be written to by FSs resulting from those VSs execution (and you use the `coherent` memory qualifier), then you're good.